# I want to hack one YouTube channel and transfer it to another person - the rightful owner, because his channel was stolen. How to start hacking?

Tags: youtube

I want to hack one YouTube channel, take away all rights from the current owner - Zell -, transfer the channel and these rights to another person - Andrei - Lagger, because Zell stole this channel, and I want to return the channel to its rightful owner. This channel: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPejF2-Ftg8udrNss... .
Please don't be kidding with this and take it seriously! What book would you recommend for such a hack? How do you recommend starting a hack? What is needed for this?
A question from the series “I don’t know and don’t understand, but I really want to”, but I’m quite good at C # (talking skills for a long time ..), I can also work with Java.
Please, help.

Comment: I hate to say it, but this is one of those things where if you have to ask, you aren't prepared to do it. "Hacking" is a massive, complicated art, and has real, legal consequences. You wouldn't be able to hack Google/YouTube, so you'd need to go for Social Engineering, which again, has all sorts of legal ramifications.

Answer (score 4):

If your account was stolen, you can open ticket with youtube help center and if they approve the fact of hacking you can return stolen account.
Follow this link for more information https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/76187?hl=en